# Grails 3 web interface with zip upload via form to a folder on the server

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a Grails 3 web interface with an upload form that writes zip files to a folder on the server.

I have already tried a lot of plugins or solutions that can be found here but nothing seems to work.

My code can be found on github (https://github.com/rm93/BIGC).
Would anyone know a solution that I could apply?

Comment: What's happening at the moment? Any error message?

Comment: Yes i get the following error: 2017-12-20 15:40:03.191 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /amplicon/upload - parameters:
SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN: 8dbfb6a7-0a10-4a1d-b9d0-c131cc3ee632
SYNCHRONIZER_URI: /amplicon/index
projectName: TestProj
pri: False
amplicon: 3
No signature of method: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile.transferTo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]

Comment: You are passing the value of mkdirs to the transferTo method (Boolean) rather than the file

Comment: Okay and how can i do it right? I'm new with Grails and this is my first time doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Instead to give a path to the transferTo method i now I give it a new file.

fileUpload.transferTo(new File("/path/to/folder/data.zip"))